# Flutter Erorr Could not find method android() for arguments on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gradle, dart

I been trying run my flutter app and I got this following error:

> Could not find method android() for arguments
> [build_i0hwgl778jv3qkhar313h400$_run_closure2@72a53595] on project
> ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Console:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\ariel\AndroidStudioProjects\Clima-Flutter\android\app\build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_i0hwgl778jv3qkhar313h400$_run_closure2@72a53595] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```